# Getting error NIntegrate::inumr:

Tags: numerical-integration

I intended to use Mathematica to perform the following numerical integration arising in the context of cosmology. I wish to evaluate the function $\sigma(R)$ at some specific points and plot those points.

$$\sigma(R) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2R^6}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dk}{k^4}P(k)
 (-3kR\cos(kR)+3\sin(kR))^2$$

$$P(k)=2\pi^2\delta_H^2\frac{k}{H_0^4}T(k)^2$$

The function $T(k)$ is defined via

$$T(x) = \frac{\log[1+0.171x]}{0.171x}[1+0.284x+(1.18x)^2+(0.399x)^3+(0.490x)^4]^{-0.25}$$

$$x = \frac{k}{k_{eq}}$$

where $\delta_H,H_0,k_{eq}$ are some constant cosmological parameters

Apparently, my naive *Mathematica* code led to the error message,

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand has evaluated to non numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{∞, 0.}}

Might I ask for some help in correcting my code?

```
H0 := 0.5*100/(3*10^5) (*Hubble rate in unit of Mpc-1, h=0.5 is used*)
keq := 0.0731*0.5^2 
T[k_] := 
  (Log[1 + 0.171 (k/keq)]/(0.171*(k/keq)))*(1 + 0.284 (k/keq) + (1.18*(k/keq))^2 + 
  (0.399*k/keq)^3 + (0.490 k/keq)^4)^(-0.25)
P[k_] := 2*Pi^2*DeltaH^2*(k*H0^(-4))*T[k]^2
f[R_] := 
  (1/(2*Pi^2*R^6))*
     NIntegrate[(P[k]/k^4)*(3*(-k*R*Cos[k*R] + Sin[k*R]))^2, {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

I attach a screen capture detailing my code, definition of the variables and the error message.

[image]

Comment: Some tips: 1) please post the code rather than an image. 2) Use `=` instead of `:=` for constants (e.g., `H0`). 3) Prevent evaluation by using `T[k_?NumericQ]:=` instead of `T[k_]:=` (and the same for `P` and `f`). 4) Those squares $\square$ in the error messages probably mean you mistyped something (e.g., `Square` does not square a number, but represents the geometrical figure instead; use `^2` for squaring). 5) Use, whenever possible, rationalised units (e.g., $G=c=\hbar=1$ or something like that) so as to have numbers of order one. This makes numerical routines much more reliable and stable

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Unfortunately, the issues still remain unsolved..

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, I do mean x^2 by Square [..]. After making the corrections, the issue still remains unsolved.

Comment: I get that `DeltaH` is undefined (that is, it has no numeric value and leads to the error).

Comment: This kind of error is easy to avoid if you just try out your functions before using them. Simply typing `P[1]` would have revealed your trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Your pasted code did not include the definition of `DeltaH`

```
H0 = 0.5*100/(3*10^5) // 
  Rationalize;(*Hubble rate in unit of Mpc-1, h=0.5 is used*)

keq = 0.0731*0.5^2 // Rationalize;

DeltaH = 19*10^-6;

T[k_] = (Log[1 + 0.171 (k/keq)]/(0.171*(k/keq)))*(1 + 
       0.284 (k/keq) + (1.18*(k/keq))^2 + (0.399*
          k/keq)^3 + (0.490 k/keq)^4)^(-0.25) // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

P[k_] = 2*Pi^2*DeltaH^2*(k*H0^(-4))*T[k]^2;
```

Since `f` is defined using a numeric technique, its argument should be restricted to numeric values.

```
f[R_?NumericQ] := (1/(2*Pi^2*R^6))*
  NIntegrate[(P[k]/k^4)*(3*(-k*R*Cos[k*R] + Sin[k*R]))^2, {k, 0, Infinity}]

f[16]

(* 1.72279 *)

Plot[f[R], {R, 2, 20}]
```

[image]

Or a `LogPlot`

```
LogPlot[f[R], {R, .01, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Let me check. Many thanks for your suggestions!